# Inserting a confirmation before deleting item from database using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Adding a confirmation before deleting item from database. I have a search.php page where users can search throught the items which are listed in table, near each item there is a delete icon.  The delete icon calls a php function "deleteItem($id)" located in deleteItem.php.

Without any confirmation all is working fine. I call the function using the below:-

```
<a href="deleteItem.php?id='.$id.'">Delete Icon</a>
```

To add a confirmation before delete I am using a javascript function which is located in the head of the search.php and is show below:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function confirmDelete(id){
      if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")){
          window.location = "deleteItem.php?id="+id;
   }else{
          // abort message ... //
      }
</script>
```

I am using an onclick event to call the confirmDelete function as follows:-

```
<a href="" onclick="confirmDelete('.$id.')">Delete Icon</a>
```

Following some time trying to fix the issue it seems that the php page deleteItem.php?id="+id is never executed.  How can I call the deleteItem function located in the deleteItem.php file using window.location or any other method from the javascript function?

Comment: `confirmDelete(<?=$id?>)`

Comment: You are highly vulnerable to SQL injection on line `window.location = "deleteItem.php?id="+id;`. I could delete your whole database by just iterating through the numbers and guessing ID's.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you are right. What is a secure way forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to print php variable for getting in javascript :

```
<a href="" onclick="confirmDelete(<?php echo $id; ?>)">Delete Icon</a>
```

Comment: The variable $id is passed successfully to the javascript function. The problem is that window.location = "deleteItem.php?id="+id; is not working.

Comment: add return false; after it

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using the below:
 Delete Link <\a>

This is one of the solutions I have tried before posting the question.  I was forgetting the return.